# Can this computer run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-requirements

I've been using Windows for ages on my computer. I would like to upgrade to Ubuntu by replacing my Windows. I'm not sure whether my computer can run 13.10 . My specs are below:

- **System:** Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 2
- **Computer:** Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU 2.53 GHz 2.53 GHz, 1 GB of RAM
- **Display adapter:** Intel(R) 82845g/gl/ge/pe/gv graphics controller v.6.14.10.4342

I have some 3 GB of virtual memory too.

Comment: How much is big your hard disk?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar ;)

Comment: @VitoShadow 19.5 GB

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know is to try it out. It should run Ubuntu though, although there maybe sluggishness. In case it is sluggish you may try out a lightweight system like Lubuntu or Xubuntu.